# Schedule textual information from an array of dates

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on an application that has a scheduling system. I have an array of dates - but I want to create a textual analysis that will provide insights onto what days there appears to be availability and select clear dates without it being overwhelming for a user, as if a calculator just spinned out 29 days in the month.

https://jsfiddle.net/23vhgsuo/2/

Json

```
[
 {date: "2023-09-14T23:00:00.000Z", value: 2}, 
 {date: "2023-09-17T23:00:00.000Z", value: 4}, 
 {date: "2023-10-24T23:00:00.000Z", value: 1}
]
```

I want to create a sentence like the following.

"Schedule a call with xxx. xxx has a clear schedule on {approximateDate}. They have some availability on {clearDates}"

```
approximateDate = "post-16th June"
clearDates = "10th and 12";
```

what would be the best way of obtaining these. get the latest date and populate the available days left in the current month or/and available days over a spread of months/time like 2 weeks?

clearDates - 10th-20th and 29th-30th. Handling data that has more complexity and gaps in the schedule of dates.

-

```
  doctorScheduleAnalysis(){
    let approximateDate = "post-16th June";
    let clearDates = "10th and 12";

    let analysis = "Schedule a call with <span>Dr name</span>. <span>Dr name</span> has a clear schedule "+ approximateDate +". They have some availability on "+clearDates+". Please select a day and a time.";
    return analysis;
  }
```

Comment: You could get the approximate date by taking the earliest date in the array and say "from {earliest date". The clear dates would depend on how many days there are in the array (more than 2?) and how early or late within the array date range you would want to give as suggestions. Also what is the `value` property in the date array for?

Comment: The clear dates are really dates in the current month/next month - that are not in the array. The array will always contain scheduled information the lowest being for 1 person. The value is the number of people booked for that day. Like 5 patients on Tuesday, 10 on Wednesday, 1 on Thursday -- so could even look at a threshold to say any dates where there are less than 3 people - promotedDates

Comment: Please provide at least a [runnable example](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/v4ua8zys/)